# Parameterize matrix with disnict values, same row sums and sum of any 2 values in a row is perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, parametrization, sums-of-squares

### Problem

Suppose I have $3\times3$ matrix $A$ with distinct values:
$$ A \in \{B \in \mathbb{N}^{3\times3} | (i,j) \neq (k,l) \implies b_{ij} \neq b_{kl}\} $$
Which also satisfies:
$$
(A \times \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix})
\in \{n^2|n\in\mathbb{N}\}^{3\times3}
$$
Meaning that the sum of any two values in a row is a perfect square.

And also:
$$ (A \times J_{3,1}) \in \{mJ_{3,1}|m\in\mathbb{N}\} $$
Meaning, the sum of each row is the same.

So I want to find cardinality of the set of all possible matrices A. And if not finite, then I want to find the corresponding aleph number and parameterize matrix A.

### My attempt

One way I thought might be possible is to try to parameterize:
$$ x_{11}^2 + x_{12}^2 + x_{13}^2 = x_{21}^2 + x_{22}^2 + x_{23}^2 = x_{31}^2 + x_{32}^2 + x_{33}^2 = 2m $$

And given that:
$$ x_{i1} < x_{i2} < x_{i3}, \\
x_{i1}^2 + x_{i2}^2 > x_{i3}^2, \\
x_{i1}^2 + x_{i2}^2 + x_{i3}^2 \mod 2 \equiv 0 $$
Then I can find:
$$ a_{i1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{i1}^2 + x_{i2}^2 - x_{i3}^2) \\ 
a_{i2} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{i3}^2 + x_{i1}^2 - x_{i2}^2) \\ 
a_{i3} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{i2}^2 + x_{i3}^2 - x_{i1}^2)
$$
And the sum will $m$. But if I understand it correctly, values of $A$ in that case might not be distinct.

Comment: Values of $a_{i,j}$ will be distinct iff $x_{i,j}$ are distinct. So you're asking if $2m$ can be written as the sum of 3 squares in 3 different ways, where all of the squares involved are distinct. $\quad$ Note that if you have one solution $A$ (which is very likely), then $k^2A$ is also another solution. Thus the answer is (very likely)  $N_0$.

Comment: @calvin-lin The sum of 3 distinct squares aren't unique. For example $10^2+5^2+2^2=8^2+7^2+4^2$. Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to get multiple square numbers with the same sum. Is there is a proof that the sum of 2 distinct squares minus 1 other square are distinct?

Comment: I did not say "the sum of 3 distinct squares has to be unique", and I'm aware that they are not (and sum up to $2m$).  $\quad$ I was only referring to "all of the squares involved are distinct".  Namely, if $ x_{i,j} $ is distinct, then so is $a_{i, h} = m - x_{i, j} ^2 $.